# Unable to write data to Amazon Kinesis from Linux server

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I have deployed my java job on a linux server to consume data from various APIs and publish it to Kinesis. My job is unable to open up the Kinesis stream to publish the data and throws below error. Any suggestion would be of great help.

> 31253 [main] ERROR com.est.producer.KinesisEstProducer - Error while writing to kinesis
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.IrrecoverableError: Pipes did not show up after calling mkfifo
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.getValue(AbstractFuture.java:299)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$Sync.get(AbstractFuture.java:286)
>           at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:116)
>           at com.est.producer.KinesisEstProducer.send(KinesisEstProducer.java:78)
>           at com.est.cable.kafka.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:102)
>   Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.IrrecoverableError: Pipes did not show up after calling mkfifo
>           at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:502)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.fatalError(Daemon.java:480)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.createPipesUnix(Daemon.java:401)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.createPipes(Daemon.java:354)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon.access$000(Daemon.java:61)
>           at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.Daemon$1.run(Daemon.java:127)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: How to you manage your credentials on the server?